# SQL server query Like

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have this table and i want to write a query that display members with the street number is 163.

the table structure is like this:

```
no_membre    nom_membre                 adresse 
3167    DIANNE  BRODEUR                 1638, 200e Avenue   
3168    RENE    LACASSE                 1638, 300e Avenue    
3209    SUZANNE LARSEN                  163, Principale 
3210    SERENA  BRODEUR                 163, Secondaire 
3210    SERENA  BRODEUR                 11638, Secondaire
```

Comment: Are you using [tag:mysql] or [tag:sql-server]? They are very different [tag:rdbms]s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query will be like so:

```
SELECT no_membre, nom_membre, adresse FROM table_name WHERE addresse LIKE '163,%'
```

Comment: I tried this before, and didnt work, it gives us streets with other numbers that contain the string 163.

Comment: Try the updated query. It's assuming that all street numbers will be separated by a comma.